# Maintaining sort order in a Silverlight datagrid

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a simple Silverlight 5 datagrid bound to a ObservableCollection of objects:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="grid_test" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" Height="268" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,186,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="744">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Agent Name" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding agentName}"  />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Campaign" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding currentCampaign}"  />

                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Currently" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding currentState}"  />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding displayTime}"  />

            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

and in the code:

> ```
> grid_test.ItemsSource = allKnownAgents;
> ```

.. and it works fine, the data is shown and updated automatically, and the user can sort the data by clicking on the column headers. However, when the data changes, the grid doesn't automatically resort - meaning the sort order isn't strictly maintained. The user needs to click the column headers again to manually reorder the data.

Is there any easy way to ask/tell Silverlight to maintain the order of data as it's changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is instead of an ObservableCollection use a [PagedCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). You have much more control over invalidating and re-applying sorting and filtering.

Comment: I'm heading down that road; however, if I issue a PagedCollectionView.Refresh(), the grid loses it's vertical scrolling position - for example, the user will have scrolled down to the bottom of the grid, the Refresh() triggers, and then when they move the scroll bar it's jumped to the top. Is there any way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: To answer my own question, I've disabled the DataGrids own scrolling and wrapped it in a ScrollViewer. That appears to fix that particular problem, now to try to "fix" sorting ...

Comment: Yay - binding to a PagedCollectionView and forcing a Refresh() seems to "fix" sort order into place too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try setting the , `Mode=TwoWay` eg:- `Binding="{Binding agentName, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't fix anything - data still ends up out of order as it changes.